# Erro ao calcular valor do decimal

Tags: c#, .net, matemática, .net-core

Preciso calcular o valor de juros, este é o código:

```
public async Task<decimal> CalculatesInterestAsync(decimal valorInicial, int meses, decimal juros)
{
    var valorFinal = (decimal)Math.Pow((double)Decimal.Multiply(valorInicial, 1 + juros), meses);

    return await Task.FromResult(valorFinal);
}
```

O valor que estou passando é:

```
valorInicial = 100
meses = 5
juros = 0.01M
```

Preciso que o valor final seja `105.10`, mas sempre é retornado `10510100501M`.

O que posso estar fazendo errado? Visto que as 5 primeiras casas são as que eu preciso.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sua fórmula está errada, a correta:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() => WriteLine(CalculatesInterest(100M, 5, 0.01M));
    public static decimal CalculatesInterest(decimal valorInicial, int meses, decimal juros) => decimal.Round(valorInicial * (decimal)Pow(1.0 + (double)juros, meses), 2);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/6aQFuX). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JYVa3e). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/CompoundInterest.cs).

Acho um infortúnio que não tenha a potência para decimal, embora não cause maiores problemas na maioria das situações. Entenda que o valor obtido não é exato, se precisa disso precisa tomar outras providências e dependendo de onde for usar precisa observar a legislação para usar corretamente, eu usei a quantidade de casas decimais que pede a pergunta, mas nem sempre é o correto de acordo com a legislação.

Note que eu tirei o assincronismo porque está piorando muito a performance (este é um mecanismo caro), não faz o menor sentido fazer um cálculo tão simples de forma assíncrona. Na verdade este mecanismo só deve ser usado para IO, não para processamento. Não use coisas, ainda mais complexas, sem entender profundamente o motivo disso existir e saber todas as consequências de uso.

Comment: Resposta perfeita, agradeço a ajuda grande Maniero